# What is the best way to work with the Android contacts?

Tags: android

I'm creating an Android APP and it will use the contacts already registered on the phone, but those who have many contacts registered may cause the APP to lose performance. So I've come to ask how best to get the name, id and phone numbers of all registered contacts and then save them to the database. This would be the first step in running the application.

After a while it would be necessary to make a comparison to check for updates or deletions. I would like to know how best to do this.

The APP will work similarly to Whatsapp, however it is not a chat application.

If you know a tutorial demonstrating how WhatsApp is done, or creating a WhatsApp template, it will also help me, because I can ask some questions as I will try to use the same way of using existing contacts as WhatsApp does.

Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question title, you are asking about contacts, not calendar.

Comment: Why are you capitalising 'app'? It's not an acronym.

Comment: Sorry, I did not see the wrong term in the title.

Comment: @le_wofl I did not understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

The below code is to get the phone contacts..

```
class LoadContactsAyscn extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<AllContact>> {
    ProgressDialog pd;
    ArrayList<AllContact> contacts;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();

        pd = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Loading Contacts",
                "Please Wait");
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<AllContact> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList<AllContact> contacts = new ArrayList<AllContact>();

        Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
        while (c.moveToNext()) {

            String contactName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String phNumber = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            AllContact allcontacts = new AllContact();
            allcontacts.setName(contactName);
            allcontacts.setNumber(phNumber);

            contacts.add(allcontacts);

        }
        c.close();

        return contacts;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<AllContact> contacts) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(contacts);

        pd.cancel();
        adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.select_text_layout, contacts);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);


    }


}
```

Comment: I'm using something like this, but when it has a lot of contacts the app crashes during execution and then it works again, but it takes a minute for that to happen, could I do it partially?